# Query to list the departments that have more employees than a certain department

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

The database I have is:

```
emp(empno, ename, job , mgr, hiredate, sal, comm, deptno)
dept(deptno, dname, loc)
```

and I am trying to find out departments that have a number of employees more than the department “Operations”

the dept table:

```
------------------------------
deptno | dname      | loc
------------------------------
10     | Accounting | New York
20     | Research   | Dallas
30     | Sales      | Chicago
40     | Operations | Boston
```

I have tried

```
SELECT `DNAME` FROM dept HAVING COUNT(*) > (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Employees, `DNAME`
FROM emp INNER JOIN dept
ON emp.DEPTNO = dept.DEPTNO
WHERE dept.DEPTNO=40
GROUP BY DNAME)
```

But I keep getting an error:

```
#4078 - Illegal parameter data types bigint and row for operation '>'
```

Comment: can you show your emp table example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need sub-query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Employees, d.`DNAME`
FROM emp e INNER JOIN 
     dept d
     ON e.DEPTNO = d.DEPTNO
GROUP BY d.`DNAME`
HAVING COUNT(*) > ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
                    FROM emp AS e1  
                    WHERE e1.DEPTNO = 40
                  )
```

Answer (score 1):

`having` requires a `group by` clause. Also, the subquery should return just one column, and does not need to use table `dept`.

Consider:

```
select d.dname 
from dept d
inner join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
group by d.dptno, d.dname
having count(*) > (select count(*) from emp e where e.deptno = 40)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT `DNAME` FROM dept GROUP BY `DNAME` HAVING COUNT(*) > (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Employees, `DNAME`
FROM emp INNER JOIN dept
ON emp.DEPTNO = dept.DEPTNO
WHERE dept.DEPTNO=40)
```