# #4078 - Illegal parameter data types int and row for operation '=' PHP MyAdmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Could you please help me understand why PHP MyAdmin displays the following communicate

//

#4078 - Illegal parameter data types int and row for operation '='

//

while I am trying to enable the subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM `user_details` 
WHERE user_id = ( select * FROM user_details where user_details.status = 102 )
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query to list the departments that have more employees than a certain department](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60774430/query-to-list-the-departments-that-have-more-employees-than-a-certain-department)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, user_id type must match request type return.

```
SELECT * FROM `user_details` 
WHERE user_id = ( select user_id FROM user_details where user_details.status = 102 )
```